# c++ passing function as array index isn't working.

Tags: c++, arrays, random, indexing

Why do the following  two codes gives different results ? 
the first one prints zeros, while the second print the random count as expected. 
using gcc 4.6.3

```
  8 int foo(){
  9   return rand() % 2;
 10 }
 11 
 12 int main()
 13 {
 14   int ar[2] = {0};              
 15   for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)  {
 16   //  int tmp  = foo();
 17   //  ar[tmp]++;
 18     ar[foo()];
 19   }
 20 
 21   for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
 22     cout << i << " : " << ar[i] << endl;
 23 }
```

~
~

```
 8 int foo(){
 9   return rand() % 2;
 10 }
 11 
 12 int main()
 13 {
 14   int ar[2] = {0};              
 15   for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)  {
 16     int tmp  = foo();
 17     ar[tmp]++;
 18     // ar[foo()];
 19   }
 20 
 21   for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
 22     cout << i << " : " << ar[i] << endl;
 23 }
```

Comment: What value do you intend `ar[1]` to be initialized with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you don't actually increment the value in the array:

```
ar[foo()]++;
//        ^
// You forgot this
```

This means all of the elements are left untouched and you get 0s as your output.